# How do I get a date result between today and 2 weeks

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a DATE column in SQL Server filled with the examples:

```
1978-03-22  
1984-04-01
1991-12-22
1986-03-31
```

Now I want all results between today and 14 days. So the entries

```
1978-03-22
1984-04-01
1986-03-31
```

should be displayed.

My SELECT statement is the following:

```
SELECT date_column FROM table WHERE CONVERT(varchar(7),date_column,100) BETWEEN CONVERT(varchar(7),DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()),100) AND CONVERT(varchar(7),DATEADD(DAY,14,GETDATE()),100)
```

What is wrong, because I get no result from this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a throughput that brings your dates up to the current year.  Then check the distance in days from that modified date.

```
select      date_column,
            distance
from        @table t
cross apply (select 
                anniversary = dateadd(year, year(getdate()) - year(date_column), date_column),
                yesterday = dateadd(day, -1, convert(date,getdate()))
             ) ap1
cross apply  (select distance = datediff(day, yesterday, anniversary)) ap2
where        ap2.distance between 0 and 14;
```

By the way, you mention that you want it from today to two weeks, but you have a -1 dateadd operator in your query.  So I wrote my code from 'yesterday' to two weeks from today, but of course you can adjust as you see fit.

Comment: That's good to hear.  If it worked for you, mark the check below the score and the up arrow above it.  Helps me out.  Thanks.  Also, Zhorov might have given a simpler solution.  So you might want to consider giving him the check (one person only) or an upvote (can be more than one person).

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two issues:

- If you are comparing with the current date and 14 days from the current date then it won't return any result because the table data has 'Year' as 1978, 1984, 1986 and 1991.
- While comparing the date, please use a format which comprised of numbers (varchar comparison might not give you the correct results).

try the following:

```
SELECT date_column
FROM @tab
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(7),date_column,112) BETWEEN CONVERT(varchar(7),DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()),112) AND CONVERT(varchar(7),DATEADD(DAY,14,GETDATE()),112)
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, with this query I also get no results

Comment: @SaMat You won't until the year value is like '2020' in your table records as you are comparing with the current 'Year' (2020) value. I hope that is clear.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you want to check only months and days. The next statement is a possible solution, (just note that you need SQL Server 2012+ for `DATEFROMPARTS()` function):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Data 
WHERE DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(date_column), DAY(date_column)) 
   BETWEEN CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) AND CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, 14, GETDATE()))
```